Construction of a bijection to prove that if $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = |\mathcal{P}(B)|$, then $|A| = |B|$ (finite case)
Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty finite sets. Suppose $F: \mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \{\emptyset\} \to \mathcal{P}(B) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ is a bijection. Then $|A| = |B|$.
I proved what is above with the cardinalities of each power set alone. What would be an explicit bijection for $f: A \to B$?
What I used was that either $A$ or $B$ had more elements than the other. So, WLOG, $|A| \leq |B|$. How can I continue from here?
Edit: My question is to seek an explicit bijection between $A$ and $B$. Is that possible?

Even if $A$ and $B$ are finite?

If $|\mathcal{P}(A) \setminus {\emptyset}| = |\mathcal{P}(B) \setminus {\emptyset}|$, then $2^{|A|} = |\mathcal{P}(A)| = |\mathcal{P}(B)| = 2^{|B|}$, and then $|A|=|B|$ by taking $\log_2$ (since they are finite).

I think the way to formalise this question would be to make it about choice functions: does a choice function on a collection of sets of size $(2^n)!$ give you a choice function on a collection of sets of size $n!$?

I am confused as to why this question which is explicitly about the finite case has an accepted answer which is entirely two links discussing the infinite case.

OP please unaccept it so I can delete it.

If the cardinality of $A$ is $k$, the cardinality of $P(A)$ is $2^k$. There are far more bijections between two sets of size $2^k$ than there are between two sets of size $k$. If  $|P(A)| = |P(B)|$ then $A$ and $B$ are of the same cardinality, so a bijection exists. But I doubt it's possible to construct a nice bijection between $A$ and $B$ starting from a random bijection between $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

For shorthand, denote: $\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) = \mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ .  
Additionally, use $F_{f}(x)$ as shorthand for $F(f)(x)$. 
We have a functor: $$F:(A\to B) \to (\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(B))  $$
defined by: $$\forall f:A\to B,\;\; F_{f}(X) = \{ f(x)   \mid x\in X \} $$
This "lifts" bijections between $A$ and $B$ to bijections between $\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)$ and $\mathcal{P}^{*}(B)$ in a "natural" fashion. 
We know it is a functor because given $f:A\to B$ and $g: B\to C$, the following $2$ properties hold:
$$ F_{g}\circ F_{f} = F_{g \;\circ \;f}\\
F_{(\text{id}_{X})} = \text{id}_{(\mathcal{P}^{*}(X))}$$
where $\text{id}_{X} : X \to X$ denotes the identity function on a set $X$.
Compositionality makes $F$ a functor.
We would like to find a functor $G$ that  "undos" $F$, in a sense. That is:
$$G: (\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(B)) \to (A\to B)   
\\G_{F_{f}} = f$$
where $G$ is a functor, meaning it obeys:
$$
G_{g}\circ G_{f} = G_{g \;\circ \;f}\\
G_{\text{id}_{(\mathcal{P}^{*}(X))}} = \text{id}_{X}$$
This hypothetical functor would have all the "nice" properties we expect from a way to bring bijections of $ (\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(B))$ down to bijections of  $A \to B$, including the "relabeling property":
If you start with a bijection from $(\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(B))$, permute the labels of the elements of $A$ (or the labels of the elements of  $B$) in it amongst themselves, then bring it "down" to a bijection from $A \to B$ it should get the same result as bringing it down first, then applying the specified relabelings.
Formally, given $a: A \to A$, $\;b: B \to B$, $\;f:\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)  \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(B)$, we have:
$$G_{F_{b} \; \circ  \; f \; \circ \; F_{a}} = b \; \circ \; G_{f} \; \circ \; a $$
This follows from the previously stated properties of $G$.

Now that we've formalized what we're looking for, let's prove it does not exist.
Theorem 1
Given $2$ bijections $x: A\to B$, $y : A\to B$, the preimage of $G$ with respect to $x$ has the same cardinality as the preimage of $G$ with respect to $y$. That is, for $I_{x} = \{X   \mid  G_X = x\}$, $I_{y}= \{Y   \mid  G_{Y} = y\}$, we have $|I_{x}| = |I_{y}|$.
Proof:
Let: $\psi : B \to B$ have the property of $\psi \circ x = y$. Then $F_{\psi}$ can give us a bijection (through composition), between $I_{x}$ and $I_{y}$. Thus $|I_{x}| = |I_{y}|$. Any two bijections from $A$ to $B$ have an equal number of elements (the elements being specific bijections from $(\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(B))$) in their associated preimages with respect to $G$.
Theorem 2
Let there be a set $A$ such that $|A| \geq 3$. 
Then a functor $G: (\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(A)) \to (A\to A)$ cannot exist.
Notes: For $|A| = 2$ you can construct $G$. There is a "nice" mapping $G: (\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(B)) \to (A\to B)$ when $|A| = |B| = 2$. I will first give the impossibility proof for $|A| = 3$, then give a general argument.
Proof:
There are $3! = 6$ bijections from $A$ to $A$. 
There are $(2^3-1)! = 5040$ bijections  from $(\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)$ to $\mathcal{P}^{*}(A))$.
The inverse image of any $A \to A$ bijection with respect to $G$ is of cardinality $5040/ 6 = 840$. 
We will be studying $|I_{\text{id}_{A}}|$, the cardinality of the set of $(\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)$ to $\mathcal{P}^{*}(A))$ bijections which $G$ maps to $\text{id}_{A}$.
Denote: $ f^n = \underbrace{f\;\circ\;f\;\circ \ldots f}_{n\ \text{times}}$.
The bijections of $f:(\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(A))$ can be considered as permutations of $7$ elements.
Consider those which cycle $5$ of the elements and leave the rest unchanged.
Denote one of these as $f_5$. 
We have ${f_{5}}^5 = \text{id}_{\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)}$. 
So ${G_{f_{5}}}^5 = G_{{f_{5}}^5} = G_{{\text{id}_{{P}^{*}(A)}}} = \text{id}_{A}$ . 
But $G_{f_{5}}$ is only a bijection from $A$ to $A$, a $3$ element set. 
It cannot have a nontrivial cycle of a length which divides $5$. Therefore $G_{f_{5}} = \text{id}_{A}$. 
We can make a similar argument for $G_{f_{7}}$, where $f_{7}:(\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(A))$ denotes a given $7$-cycle of $\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)$. We have $G_{f_{7}} = \text{id}_{A}$.
The number of $5$-cycles of $\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)$ is $\binom{7}{5}*4! = 504$.
The number of $7$-cycles of $\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)$ is $6! = 720$.
From this we get $|I_{\text{id}_{A}}| \geq 504 + 720 > 840$, contradicting theorem $1$. 
We cannot construct the functor $G: (\mathcal{P}^{*}(A) \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(A)) \to (A\to A)$ when $|A| = 3$.

Now for the general case. We will rely on $2$ lemmas:
Lemma 1
For $n > 2$, there exists a prime $p$ such that $n < p < 2^n$.
This follows from the Bertrand–Chebyshev theorem.
Lemma 2
Let $n$ be a natural number, and $i > 1$ be an odd number. Then the $i$-cycles $f_{i}$ (on a set of $n$ elements) generate the alternating group $\mathcal{A}_{n}$.
Proof:
Let $f_{i}$ be a $i$-cycle and $\alpha_{k ,f_i(k)}$ be an inversion of $2$ consecutive elements of the cycle $f_{i}$. Then $g_{i} = \alpha_{k ,f_i(k)}   \; \circ \; f_{i} \circ \; \alpha_{k ,f_i(k)}$ will also be an $i$-cycle, and $f_{i}\circ g^{-1}_{i}$ will be a $3$-cycle $(f^{-1}(k), \; k, \; f(k))$. Thus we can generate all $3$-cycles, which generate the alternating group $\mathcal{A}_{n}$, which contains $f_{i}$, since odd cycles have even parity.
Now for the proof:
Let $A$ be a set with $|A| = n >3$. 
Due to theorem $1$, we have $|I_{\text{id}_{A}}| = \frac{(2^n-1)!}{n!}$. 
Due to lemma $1$, there exists a prime $p$ with $n < p < 2^n$. Generalizing the composition argument of the previous proof, we know that $G_{f_{p}} = \text{id}_{A}$ for all $p$-cycles $f_{p}$ of $\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)$. 
Due to lemma 2 and the composition property of $G$, we can say: $\forall \alpha\in \mathcal{A}_{(\mathcal{P}^{*}(A))},\; G_{\alpha} = \text{id}_{A}$. 
Ie. $G$ will map any permutation which is of the alternating group of  $\mathcal{P}^{*}(A)$ to $\text{id}_{A}$.
We have $|I_{\text{id}_A}| \geq |\mathcal{A}_{(\mathcal{P}^{*}(A))}| =  \frac{(2^n-1)!}{2} >  \frac{(2^n-1)!}{n!}$ for $n > 2$, contradicting theorem $1$. This completes the proof.

I wonder if by looking for a functor on category containing $P^(A), P^(B)$ and all isomorphisms one could find a result for $A \ne B$. This is isomorphic to the category of all isomorphisms between two symmetric groups.

I've added an argument that should work for the general case. I think it's unlikely to construct $G$ even if  $|A| \neq |B|$, at least not in a general sense.

Here is the explicit construction for $G$ when $|A| = |B| = 2$ . Let $A = {a,b}, B = {x.y}$. We have: $$G({a}\to {x},{b}\to{y}, {a,b}\to{x,y}) = (a\to x, b \to y)$$ $$G({a}\to {x},{b}\to{x,y}, {a,b}\to{y}) = (a\to y, b \to x)$$  The rest of the cases can be obtained by relabeling. It basically measures how much cardinality the powerset bijection  preserves (there exists at least 1 mapping from a set of cardinality $1$ to a set of cardinality $1$), to decide how to construct the function.

I don't have an answer, but I would like to propose a way of making the question rigorous which I think is interesting and amenable to representation theory.
I'll start with an unsatisfying answer: if you pick a way of numbering $B$ from $1$ to $n$ then you have an ordering on $2^B$ (interpret each element as a $\le n$ digit binary number). We can then order $\{a\}$ for each $a \in A$ using the bijection with $P(B)$, and use our ordering of $A$ and $B$ to construct a bijection $A \to B$. However, this is kind of trivial, and what choice of ordering of $B$ you make affects which bijection you end up with. So this doesn't specify a unique bijection if we can make different choices about how to order $B$.
I think the satisfying non-trivial version of this problem is to find a way of doing this which is invariant under relabeling of the elements of $A$ and $B$, so that you specify a unique order without making any additional choice. Specifically, our problem is to find a function $\phi: iso(P(A), P(B)) \to iso(A, B)$ with the appropriate invariances. I'm using $iso(A, B)$ to denote the set of bijections $A \to B$.
We can describe a relabeling of $A$ as a permutation $\sigma_A$ of $A$, and then $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ act on $iso(A, B)$ by taking the function $f: a_i \mapsto b_i$ to the function $\sigma_B f \sigma_A : \sigma_A^{-1}(a_i) \mapsto \sigma_B(b_i)$.
$\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ also act on $iso(P(A), P(B))$ by taking the function $g: A'_i \mapsto B'_i$ to the function $\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A} : \sigma_A^{-1}[A'_i] \mapsto \sigma_B[B'_i]$ which can alternatively be viewed as the action of permutations of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$, $\bar{\sigma_A}$ and $\bar{\sigma_B}$, where $\bar{\sigma_A}(A') = \sigma_A[A']$. I will call $\bar{\sigma_A}$ the permutation of $P(A)$ induced by $\sigma_A$.
So the property of $\phi$ that we want is that if $\phi(g) = f$, for any relabelings $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$, $\sigma$, $\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A}$ gets mapped to $\sigma_B f \sigma_A$.
In summary, we want a $\phi: iso(P(A), P(B)) \to iso(A, B)$ such that for any permutations $\sigma_A, \sigma_B$ of $A, B$,
$$\phi(\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A}) = \sigma_B \phi(g) \sigma_A$$
Note that this implies something about choice functions. If we have a choice function, $\psi$ on $\{iso(P(A_i), P(B_i)) | i \in I\}$, where $|A_i| = |B_i| = n$, we automatically get another choice function $\psi'$ on $\{iso(A_i, B_i) | i \in I\}$ by simply applying $\phi$ to each choice given by $\psi$. The invariance property means our answer doesn't depend on our labelling, so we have gotten from $\psi$ to $\psi'$ in a choice-free way.

Some notes making a start on this problem:
Now, by acting as $\bar{\sigma_A}$ and $\bar{\sigma_B}$, $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ have actions on $iso(P(A), P(B))$ that commute with each other, so we have an action of $\Gamma = Sym(A) \times Sym(B)$ on $iso(P(A), P(B))$ We can thus partition $iso(P(A), P(B))$ into orbits, and if a valid $\phi$ exists, we can restrict its domain to $O$ for each orbit $O$, to make a mini $\phi$ with the same property.
Conversely, if for each orbit $O$ we can make a mini $\phi$, we can stitch these together to make a $\phi$ for the whole of $iso(P(A), P(B))$. Stitching together the orbits can't cause there to be a $g, \sigma_A, \sigma_B$ such that $\phi(\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A}) \ne \sigma_B f \sigma_A$, because $\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A}$ is in the same orbit as $g$, so it would have broken the mini $\phi$ for that orbit already, if such a counterexample existed. This means we have a $\phi$ iff we have a mini $\phi$ for each orbit.
On a given orbit $O$, if we fix $\phi(g) = f$, that already fixes the value of every $\phi$ on the whole of $O$, because everything in $O$ is of the form $\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A}$ and $\phi(\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A}) = \sigma_B f \sigma_A$. It might fix the value of $g' \in O$ multiple ways if $g'$ can be written in multiple ways $g' = \bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A} = \bar{\tau_B} g \bar{\tau_A}$ so we get a well-defined function mini $\phi$ iff whenever $\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A} = \bar{\tau_B} g \bar{\tau_A}$ we have the induced values of $\phi(\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A}), \phi(\bar{\tau_B} g \bar{\tau_A})$ equal, i.e. $\sigma_B f \sigma_A = \tau_B f \tau_A$.
But we can simplify this condition, saying whenever $\bar{\tau_B}^{-1} \bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A} \bar{\tau_A}^{-1} = g$ we have $\tau_B^{-1} \sigma_B f \sigma_A \tau_A^{-1}$, and $\tau_B^{-1} \sigma_B$ and $\sigma_A \tau_A^{-1}$ can both take any value, in $Sym(A)$, $Sym(B)$ respectively, so our condition becomes:
There is some $f \in iso(A, B)$ such that whenever $\bar{\sigma_B} g \bar{\sigma_A} = g$ we have $\sigma_B f \sigma_A = f$.
It is my suspicion that such an $f$ will exist for any orbit $O$, and thus that a $\phi$ does exist, regardless of what we take $n = |A| = |B|$ to be.
